# Using TypeScript Type Predicates on private properties

Tags: typescript, narrowing, type-narrowing

I have a class which has a private, optional property (`private foo?: Foo`). Within the private code of the class, I need to be able to validate that this property exists, so that I can handle failure once at the beginning of the method and then deal with it as non-optional in the rest of the block.

The code below works like a charm *if* `foo` is public. However, since I need foo to be private, it doesn't work. Instead of validating `this` as conforming to `FooBar & FooContainer`, the type of `this` becomes `never`.

This behavior totally makes sense for public usage where I don't want to allow external code to validate the existence of a private property. However, I am trying to find a type-predicate-like solution I can use privately within my class to make the property in question non-optional.

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

interface FooContainer {
    foo: Foo;
}

class FooBar {
    private foo?: Foo;
    bar?: string

    constructor(foo?: Foo, bar?: string) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    private isFooContainer(): this is FooContainer {
        const { foo } = this;
        return typeof foo !== "undefined";
    }
    
    printFoo() {
        if (!this.isFooContainer()) throw new Error("There is no foo!!!!");
        // For the rest of this method `this.foo` should be typed as `Foo` rather than `Foo | undefined`
        console.log(this.foo.bar); // <--- No optional chaining (`this.foo?.bar`) required here.`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it as simple as inlining the check itself? I wonder if I've missed the purpose of having an interface and a predicate but this seems fine to me...

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

class FooBar {
    #foo?:Foo;
    bar?:string;

    constructor(foo?:Foo, bar?:string) {
        this.#foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    
    printFoo() {
        if(typeof this.#foo === "undefined") throw new Error("There is no foo!!!!");
        console.log(this.#foo.bar); 
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gNwEC%20BBCANnNdWpgBC5HAWLIAxDEwB%20ChnQtCxMlDm16IZh2VEE6EBoCuCMOigAKaejkKANKXLq6jAJSjd45GAAWwagB0UpjIALzI1kpexL7%20AaphjlBRxOyeYsQADppgChbueJ7iwDAWYACemRDoMN5%20gcFYoc3IAERGIAAmEDCgEJ2t7r5Q6ADuyCAQ4wCiUCOWrQAqPtAo-hNY1gCEO1uDKdH6huhcEAFc6Axl9UHW8eSuTMgZRGmsQA)

Comment: Technically this works and is an alternative I've considered. It still feels messy to expose the raw checker logic again and again. Consider that there are about 30 other methods just like `printFoo`. A type predicate wraps up the checker logic. Anytime I want I can update the underlying checker logic for all 30 methods by tweaking my predicate. WIth the above solution, if I want to tweak the logic, I have to tweak each of the 30 methods.

Comment: The fallback I'm kinda leaning toward is just checking and extracting foo...
```ts
const getFooOrThrow = (): Foo => {
  const { foo } = this;
  if (!foo) throw new FooUnexpectedlyUndefined();
  return foo;
}
//..
const foo = this.getFooOrThrow();
```
Technically, this is safer. But you have to be careful and be sure to account for any reassignments in the original this.foo:
```ts
this.foo = { bar: 1 };
const foo = this.getFooOrThrow();
this.foo = { bar: 2 };
print(foo.bar); // 1
print(this.foo?.bar); // 2
```